# Return concatenated set of member IEnumerables from List of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have node objects

```
public class Node {
 private Boolean isStart;
 private IEnumerable<int> memberIds;
}
```

in an IEnumerable `IEnumerable<Node>`

And want to get the all the memberids where the node has  isStart=true;

My current answer is:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetStartingMembers(IEnumerable<node> nodeList) {
  IEnumerable<Node> startingNodes = nodeList.Where(n.isStartingNode == true);
  IEnumerable<int> startingMembers = new List<int>();
  foreach (var node in startingNodes) {
     startingMembers = startingMembers.Concat(node.memberIds);
  }
}
```

But this seems way too cumbersome - there has to be a better way - any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a fit for codereview.stackexhange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
IEnumerable<int> startingMembers = nodeList.Where(n => n.isStartingNode)
    .SelectMany(x => x.memberIds)
    .ToList();
```

Ref: [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.0)

Answer (score 1):

First your code sample doesn't compile: wrong member names, wrong class names, incorrect access modifiers. But if we change all that to compile your code reduces to:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetStartingMembers(IEnumerable<Node> nodeList) 
    => nodeList.Where(n => n.isStart == true).SelectMany(n => n.memberIds);

public class Node
{
    public Boolean isStart;
    public IEnumerable<int> memberIds;
}
```